# Send header 404 if id != $_get['id']

Tags: php, mysql, sql, http-status-code-404

SQL query like this,

```
$uid = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, lastname, email FROM users WHERE id = '$uid'");
```

How to print a 404 header if the id != value of $_GET['id']?

Comment: $_GET['id'] = "0' OR true; DELETE FROM `table`;";

Comment: @AndyPerlitch I thought the mysql_ library didn't allow chained queries like that?

Comment: @AndyPerlitch, didn't get you solution sorry, where should that code be placed?

Comment: @JohanLarsson That's not a solution. He's pointing out a vulnerability in your code know as SQL injection.

Comment: @stevether, that's right, my code is not production ready yet, I know I have to think about that. by the way thank about that Bobby Tables ;)

Comment: ah yes, little bobby tables, we call him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, lastname, email FROM users WHERE id = '{$uid}'");
if (!result || mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
```

Also note, you should move away from deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Also also note, [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: I'm getting an error, Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent... at the same line where I placed the code. (You are on the right track for solving the issue)

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.4 you can also use `http_response_code()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php.

Comment: @JohanLarsson That's a separate issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php

Comment: "Move away from" is a polite way of saying "You should never have used them in the first place" because they're extremely dangerous if not used correctly, and way too easy to use incorrectly. It would not be a bad idea to rip out all your `mysql`-based code and replace it with `mysqli` or PDO right now because you will have to do this eventually anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure which `id` you refer to, but you are looking for something along the lines of:

```
if (id != $_GET['id'])
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
```